# Clan lib error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clanCore-static-mt-debug.lib'?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker-errors

```
1>------ Build started: Project: clanlib 2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Build started 24-07-2012 16:34:27.
1>InitializeBuildStatus:
1>  Touching "C:\Users\Voldy\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\clanlib 2\clanlib 2\Build\Debug\clanlib 2\clanlib 2.unsuccessfulbuild".
1>ClCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>ManifestResourceCompile:
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'clanCore-static-mt-debug.lib'
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.16
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

This is the error I am getting this error when trying to make a clan lib application. Please help me resolve the prob.

Comment: `cannot open file` i think this is a pretty big hint to what is wrong... Add this path to your include lib settings in VC.

Answer (score 1):

From official [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ts7eyw4s%28v=vs.71%29.aspx), possible causes:

- Not enough disk space
- File does not exist. For example, you will get this error if you try to use the PGINSTRUMENT parameter to the /LTCG linker option on a machine with a 32-bit operating system.
- When specifying libraries in a project's property pages dialog box, library names should be separated by spaces (and not commas).
- Incorrect filename or path.
- Invalid drive specification.
- Insufficient file permissions.
- Path for filename expands to more than 260 characters.
- If the given file is named LNKn, which is a filename generated by the linker for a temporary file, the directory specified in the TMP environment variable may not exist, or more than one directory is specified for the TMP environment variable. (Only one directory path should be specified for the TMP environment variable.)
- If the error message occurs for a library name, and you recently ported the .mak file from a previous Microsoft Visual C++ development system, the library may no longer be valid. Ensure that the library still exists in this circumstance.
- Another program may have the file open and the linker cannot write to it.
- Incorrect LIB environment variable. For information on how to update the LIB environment variable, see VC++ Directories, Projects, Options Dialog Box. Make sure any directories with libraries you need are listed here.

Answer (score 1):

You should have to include the lib file in the project property.

**Project Property-->Linker-->Input-->Additional Dependencies-->clanCore-static-mt-debug.lib**

Answer (score 1):

ClanLib uses pragmas under Visual Studio to automatically link required libraries. So if you get that message, it means Visual Studio can't locate the lib files. It probably means you haven't set up the directories where Visual Studio should look for library files correctly.

Detailed explanations how to set this up is located at http://clanlib.org/wiki/VisualStudio2010GlobalIncludes